# How to get a linked relationship

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have base model

```
public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int GroupVag { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Vagon> Vagons { get; set; }
}

public class Vagon 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nom_Vag { get; set; }
    //[Required]
    public int NumberGroup { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Group")]
    public int? GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SPR4664> SPR4664s { get; set; }
}
```

My viewModel

```
public class ViewModelAddVag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Name vag")]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(8, ErrorMessage = "incorrect")]
    public string Nom_Vag { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Group vag")]
    //[Required]
    public int NumberGroup { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "TrainingType")]
    [UIHint("DropDownList")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GroupDictionary { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like get on View DropDownList table Group.
I did ViewModel for it. But I can't figure it out how to do it?
I guess I should get it in ViewModel use property Get

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GroupDictionary { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I wanted to get:

View

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            
                Grops <br />
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, ViewBag.Group as SelectList, null, new { @class = "btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" })
            
            <select name="TrainingTypeId" class="btn btn-light dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" aria-label="Default select example">
                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Group)
                {
                    <option value="@item.Value">
                        @item.Text
                    </option>
                }
            </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        SelectList groupsList = new SelectList(db.groups, "Id", "GroupVag");
        ViewBag.Group = groupsList;
        return View();
    }
```